# Outbound call with TTS response that includes DTMF input

Tags: node-red, vonage

I am new to programming so have chosen node red as an easy way into Nexmo. I would like to replace a conventional dialler alarm system with ngrok and Nexmo. When an alarm input is active up to four recipients would receive voice calls until one accepted the call with a DTMF response ie "0". I can create the outbound call but I am not able to continue the call by returning a text to speech that includes the dtmf response as the call always ends prematurely. Is anyone aware of a tutorial or project that uses a simmilar workflow. I am a novice in this area and wouls appreciate a bit f gentle steering. Thanks

Comment: The outbound call starts but do you hear anything at all? Can you share the configuration of the call, are you setting an NCCO when you start the call? There is some DTMF setup in this blog post https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2019/10/07/conference-call-node-red-dr if that helps? (I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve here)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have an inject node, talk node, input node, talk node & create call in that order with a separate voice webhook and return nco. The number form the inject node is called and the talk node text is played as normal. The dtmf input is accepted and returned as an event but then the call ends I am not able to continue the reply to the caller that includes there dtmf input. ie "you pressed 0 to accept the alarm or 1 to decline" etc. perhaps I need to use a function node and drop back to javascript but the will stretch me.

Comment: Ah if you want to do something after the input node then you need to return additional NCCO actions to the dtmf event. Try moving that second talk to be after the input handler and then close that off with a 'return ncco' action.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Sam, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example flow of what I think you are wanting to do. It makes the first call and if the recipient presses 0 then it responds to them with an acknowledgement and ends there, if they don't press anything (input times out) or they press another digit it then goes down to repeat the same process for the 2nd call, you can extend this flow for 3, 4, 5.. people to call in the chain as you like, hopefully its clear enough where to do this, 
The key thing is using a switch node to examine the DTMF input, there's a new tutorial on this just gone live https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2020/01/08/interactive-voice-response-node-red-dr

```js
[{"id":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"ebcf4889.76fde8","type":"inject","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","name":"Go","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":170,"y":340,"wires":[["2a747d63.4890fa"]]},{"id":"19db6c23.b9df34","type":"voice webhook","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","name":"","url":"/input1","method":"get","x":160,"y":580,"wires":[["15fd1045.7af4f"]]},{"id":"15fd1045.7af4f","type":"switch","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","name":"","property":"call.dtmf","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"eq","v":"0","vt":"str"},{"t":"empty"},{"t":"eq","v":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9","vt":"str"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":3,"x":410,"y":620,"wires":[["699c7122.0eaec8"],["3beed2b7.667836","ac144668.83059"],["3beed2b7.667836","ac144668.83059"]]},{"id":"3beed2b7.667836","type":"return ncco","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","name":"","x":990,"y":520,"wires":[]},{"id":"699c7122.0eaec8","type":"talk","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","text":"Thank you for accepting, goodbye","voicename":"","bargein":false,"loop":"","level":"","x":650,"y":520,"wires":[["3beed2b7.667836"]]},{"id":"20e40559.a7d7a2","type":"comment","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","name":"First Call","info":"","x":160,"y":240,"wires":[]},{"id":"46ce6a0.6066318","type":"comment","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","name":"Second Call","info":"","x":150,"y":800,"wires":[]},{"id":"22e9b182.875fc6","type":"createcall","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","creds":"d21ce4e8.53a06","endpoint":"phone","to":"14155551111","dtmfanswer":"","wsuri":"","headers":"","sipuri":"","extension":"","from":"12125551212","ringingtimer":"","lengthtimer":"","machinedetection":"","answer":"","answertype":"fixed","eventurl":"","x":770,"y":340,"wires":[["bfa7566f.24217"]]},{"id":"2a747d63.4890fa","type":"talk","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","text":"Hello World this is node red calling, press 0 to acknowledge","voicename":"","bargein":true,"loop":"","level":"","x":360,"y":340,"wires":[["6ee0fc41.35d424"]]},{"id":"bfa7566f.24217","type":"debug","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":1030,"y":340,"wires":[]},{"id":"6ee0fc41.35d424","type":"input","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","eventurl":"https://demo.nodered.nexmodev.com/input1","eventmethod":"get","timeout":"","maxdigits":"1","submitonhash":false,"x":550,"y":340,"wires":[["22e9b182.875fc6"]]},{"id":"e36fa6f1.15008","type":"debug","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":910,"y":900,"wires":[]},{"id":"9cb58bf1.4e28b8","type":"createcall","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","creds":"d21ce4e8.53a06","endpoint":"phone","to":"14155552222","dtmfanswer":"","wsuri":"","headers":"","sipuri":"","extension":"","from":"12125551212","ringingtimer":"","lengthtimer":"","machinedetection":"","answer":"","answertype":"fixed","eventurl":"","x":690,"y":900,"wires":[["e36fa6f1.15008"]]},{"id":"40f83c45.9190dc","type":"input","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","eventurl":"https://demo.nodered.nexmodev.com/input2","eventmethod":"get","timeout":"","maxdigits":"1","submitonhash":false,"x":490,"y":900,"wires":[["9cb58bf1.4e28b8"]]},{"id":"ac144668.83059","type":"talk","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","text":"Hello World this is node red calling, press 0 to acknowledge","voicename":"","bargein":true,"loop":"","level":"","x":310,"y":900,"wires":[["40f83c45.9190dc"]]},{"id":"f61e68c4.14919","type":"voice webhook","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","name":"","url":"/input2","method":"get","x":190,"y":1060,"wires":[["3c8e7f74.bf88f"]]},{"id":"3c8e7f74.bf88f","type":"switch","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","name":"","property":"call.dtmf","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"eq","v":"0","vt":"str"},{"t":"empty"},{"t":"eq","v":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9","vt":"str"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":3,"x":440,"y":1100,"wires":[["69a04958.8ed8"],["e9fa46e5.4371f8"],["e9fa46e5.4371f8"]]},{"id":"e9fa46e5.4371f8","type":"return ncco","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","name":"","x":1010,"y":1060,"wires":[]},{"id":"69a04958.8ed8","type":"talk","z":"4745e6f.c0a4f18","text":"Thank you for accepting, goodbye","voicename":"","bargein":false,"loop":"","level":"","x":680,"y":1000,"wires":[["e9fa46e5.4371f8"]]},{"id":"d21ce4e8.53a06","type":"nexmovoiceapp","z":"","name":"NR1.0.0 Test"}]
```

[image]